# Como fazer com que ao se clicar em uma div, um link do elemento filho seja aberto?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, blogger

Tenho na página inicial do meu blog a lista de postagens. Estou tentando fazer com que ao se clicar no espaço em branco (onde se encontra o resumo da postagem), o link desta mesma postagem seja aberto. Ou seja: ao invés de o link ficar restrito apenas à imagem, ao título e ao botão de continuar lendo, gostaria que cada `div` de cada artigo (o `#body-post`) funcionasse como se um card. É possível isso?

Inseri o código para vocês terem uma ideia do que quero implementar. Ao clicar na `div` no artigo 1, chama o link do artigo 1, e assim sucessivamente.

```css
article {border: 3px solid #000; padding:5px; margin:5px}
article:hover {border-color:red}
article:hover img {border-bottom:5px solid red}
article:hover h2 a {color:red}
article:hover #readmore a {background-color:red}

img {width:75px; height:75px; float:left}

h2 a, #body-post {text-align:center; margin:15px}

#readmore a {float:right; bottom:30px; position:relative; padding:5px; background-color:green; color:#fff}
```

```html
<!-- ARTIGO 1 -->
<article>

 <a href="http://www.artigo1.html"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d0/Alvorada_de_outono_na_Imagem_de_Minas.JPG"></a>
  
<h2><a href="http://www.artigo1.html">Artigo 1</a></h2>

<div id="body-post">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis pharetra massa, aliquam dapibus...
</div>
  
<div id="readmore">
<a href="http://www.artigo1.html">
Continue lendo...</a>
</div>
</article>

<!-- ARTIGO 2 -->
<article>

 <a href="http://www.artigo2.html"><img src="https://i1.wp.com/socientifica.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/image_7150_1e-Hubble-Legacy-Field.jpg?fit=1920%2C1773&ssl=1"></a>
  
<h2><a href="http://www.artigo2.html">Artigo 2</a></h2>

<div id="body-post">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis pharetra massa, aliquam dapibus...
</div>
  
<div id="readmore">
<a href="http://www.artigo2.html">
Continue lendo...</a>
</div>
</article>

<!-- ARTIGO 3 -->
<article>

 <a href="http://www.artigo3.html"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/11/21/17/02/lion-66898_960_720.jpg"></a>
  
<h2><a href="http://www.artigo3.html">Artigo 3</a></h2>

<div id="body-post">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis pharetra massa, aliquam dapibus...
</div>
  
<div id="readmore">
<a href="http://www.artigo3.html">
Continue lendo...</a>
</div>
</article>
```

Comment: Tens o acesso ao JavaScript da página?

Comment: @LeAndrade Sim, Leandro, tenho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia fazer um direcionamento via JavaScript, mas aí perde a função de abrir o link numa nova aba que os links `<a>` possuem ao clicar com o botão direito do mouse:

```
$(function(){
   $(".readmore") // seleciona o elemento pela classe
   .parent() // seleciona o elemento pai, no caso, o <article>
   .on("click", function(){ // atribui o <article> ao evento click
      // captura o link no atributo "href" do link dentro de .readmore
      // do <article> clicado e faz o direcionamento
      location.href = $(".readmore a", this).attr("href");
   });
});
```

É preciso trocar o id `#readmore` por classe: `.readmore`, porque você está repetindo o mesmo id, o que é incorreto no HTML. Um `id` deve ser único na página.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, Sam! Não conhecia o ```parent``` do jQuery. Muitíssimo obrigado, meu caro!

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro que você use o elemento `<a>` como o próprio card. Algo nessa linha:

```html
<article>
 <a href="http://www.artigo3.html">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/11/21/17/02/lion-66898_960_720.jpg">

  <h2>Artigo 3</h2>

  <p id="body-post">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis pharetra massa, aliquam dapibus...</p>

  <p>Continue lendo...</p>
 </a>
</article>
```

Antigamente o padrão da linguagem não permitia que tivéssemos elementos de bloco (`h2`, `p`) dentro de elementos `a`, mas hoje essa construção já é permitida e faz sentido também semanticamente.

Comment: Não posso fazer dessa forma, Afonso, porque acho que não consigo alterar, no momento, a estrutura da página inicial do Blogger (acredito que interferiria nas outras páginas). Mas, muito obrigado pela dica!